# can't open octet-stream files which is downloaded from akka http server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scala, akka, akka-http

i've created akka server which send file when user post some json structure to sever but i can't open the file which is sent by server

https://i.stack.imgur.com/leyvf.jpg

**Akka http server (POST METHOD) => http://localhost:5004/download**

val file = new File("src/main/resources/"+path)

```
HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK,entity=HttpEntity.fromFile(ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`,file = file)).withHeaders(
               scala.collection.immutable.Seq(
                 RawHeader("Content-Disposition",s"attachment; filename=${file.getName}"),
                 RawHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","Content-Disposition"),
                 RawHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*"),
               )
             )
```

**Javascript/React code**

```
downloadFile = ()=>{
        const tokenData = {
            token:this.state.token,
            password:this.state.password
        }
       axios.post("http://localhost:5004/download",tokenData).then(res=>{
        var a = document.createElement('a');   
        console.log(res.data)
        var blob = new Blob([res.data], {type:"application/octet-stream"});
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.download = res.headers["content-disposition"].split("=")[1];
        a.click();
       }).catch(res=>{
           this.setState({
               error:true
           })
       })
    }
```

Comment: Can you isolate the problem to either the front end or back end code? For example, try making the same request to the server using `curl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**problem solved!!**

i just used vanilla Fetch API instead of axios, i don't know what's wrong with axios